# How can I transform this dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

```
  total agricultura extrativas transformadoras eletricidade construcao comercio alojamentoResta~ transportesArma~ gender
  <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>           <dbl>        <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>      <chr>
1 1274         928.      1394.           1232.        2994.       987.    1170.             893.            1405.      Male.
2 1047.        820.      1479.            926.        2766.      1052     1017.             765             1516.      Female.
```

I want to have  a new df, with only 3 columns:

1. Sector, with all the names(df) ;
2. Values, with all the corresponding values of each name;
3. Gender, where for each value of each sector I
   add the corresponding value and the gender value of the last column of the original df;

sample:

```
sector value gender
<chr> <dbl> <chr>
1 total 1274 Male
```

...

This will basically be a dataset with the number of rows = 2*lenght(names(df)).

I was trying to divide this problem in parts and the join them with:

```
data.frame(sector = aux1, values = aux2, Gender =aux3)
```

But Im having a lot of problems, namely making a vector where the names(df) is stacked together, doubling its size. I tried:

```
aux1 <- cbind(names(df),names(df))
```

and the same with rbind which didnt work.

Any ideas in how I can achieve this new df?

Thank you.

Comment: Use pivot_longer except on gender col

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% pivot_longer(cols = -Gender, names_to = "sector", values_to = "value")
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you !!

Comment: Please also accept if this served the purpose. Glad to have been help.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `melt` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df), id.var = 'Gender')
```